# ensure removal of password at end of string using StringBuilder with java

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

I need to ensure that always at the end of this string when there is a password, from there it leaves the password masked and does not display.

Remembering that in the end, the value cannot always be `cards-app`, it can be a different value, I need to mask the end of this string from `&password=` in order to mask the password.

### How can I do this for sure using StringBuilder?

Ex.:

https://hlg-gateway.odsus.com.br/token?grant_type=password&username=cards-app&password=cards-app;

expected output:

https://hlg-gateway.odsus.com.br/token?grant_type=password&username=cards-app&password=######;

**This information is displayed in the log, I just want to make sure the end of the string is masked to not display the password.**

Comment: It's easier to do with a String: `url = url.replaceAll("&password=[^&]+", "&password=######");`. Or if that semicolon is intended, make it `[^;]`.

Comment: Is _StringBuilder_ a requirement?  You could also just use a _String_.

Comment: Must the length of the mask equal the length of the plaintext password? Note: recommend not because it would give away password length info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a note, *StringBuilder* is not required here—you could just use basic string concatenation.

```java
String string = "https://hlg-gateway.odsus.com.br/token?grant_type=password&username=cards-app&password=cards-app;";
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(string);
int indexOfA = string.indexOf("&password=");
indexOfA = string.indexOf('=', indexOfA);
int indexOfB = string.indexOf(';', indexOfA);
String mask = "#".repeat(indexOfB - indexOfA - 1);
stringBuilder.replace(indexOfA, indexOfB, mask);
```

Output

```
https://hlg-gateway.odsus.com.br/token?grant_type=password&username=cards-app&password=#########;
```

And, without the *StringBuilder*, you could use the following concatenation—in place of the *replace* method call.

```java
string = string.substring(0, indexOfA + 1) + mask + string.substring(indexOfB);
```